# How to get an AWS secret in a Makefile

Tags: python, makefile, aws-cli, aws-secrets-manager

I'm very new to Makefiles and would like to know how to get AWS secrets stored in the AWS Secret Manager in the Makefile and set variables which will further be used in the Makefile. These variables are the ones that will be used to connect MySQL (username, password). So if I'm just able to get the password secret value in DB_PASSWORD := .

I am successful in getting the secrets in the 'python code' following the link below (you can directly go to the code at the end of the page on the below link):
https://www.capside.com/labs/using-aws-secrets-manager/

I couldn't however find any way of doing it in the Makefile.

My file looks something like:

```
DB := prod
# DB := staging

ifeq ($(DB),staging)
DB_HOST := <staging database>
OBJ_DIR := ./obj/staging
else
DB_HOST := <prod database>
OBJ_DIR := ./obj/prod
endif
DB_PASSWORD := <password>
DB_USER := <user>
DB_PORT := 3306
DB_DATABASE := <database name>

MKDIR := mkdir -p
RM := rm
SRC_DIR := ./sql
SRC_FILES := $(wildcard $(SRC_DIR)/*.sql)
OBJECTS := $(SRC_FILES:%.sql=%.o)
OBJECTS := ${subst $(SRC_DIR),$(OBJ_DIR),$(OBJECTS)}

export MYSQL_PWD=$(DB_PASSWORD)

all: deploy

$(OBJ_DIR):
    $(MKDIR) $@

$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o: $(SRC_DIR)/%.sql
    @cat $< | mysql -h $(DB_HOST) -P $(DB_PORT) -u $(DB_USER) $(DB_DATABASE)
    @touch $@
    @echo "Deploy of $< !"

clean:
    $(RM) $(OBJECTS)

deploy: $(OBJ_DIR) $(OBJECTS)
    @echo 'CALL create_views();' | mysql -h $(DB_HOST) -P $(DB_PORT) -u $(DB_USER) $(DB_DATABASE)
    @echo "Deploy complete on $(DB) !"
```

NOTE/TIP: The secret can also be retrieved by the AWS CLI:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/secretsmanager/get-secret-value.html

Comment: Exactly. If you know how to get it from AWS CLI, just use the CLI to get the output you want.

Comment: Yea to follow up, whats the need to retrieve the secret from the MakeFile for? If you can do it python, that should work. There's also the python caching client - https://github.com/aws/aws-secretsmanager-caching-python

Comment: What is stopping you from using the CLI in Makefile and the get the secret?

Comment: The result is a JSON from the AWS CLI, I can't figure out how to get the 'password' value and then use it in the MakeFile

Answer (score 1):

Since you know how to get the secret using the AWS CLI, you can use JQ to get values from the output.

Try something like this:

```
get-secret-username: 
@ $(eval USERNAME = $(shell aws secretsmanager get-secret-value --secret-id vikings-aurora-postgres-secret | jq -r '.SecretString' | jq '.username'))
@ echo "username: $(USERNAME)"
```

In this example, I used JQ's -r to parse the SecretString from secrets manager (which is a JSON string with escaped characters), and then get the value I wanted from the result of the first JQ command.

Refer to JQ manual on invoking JQ to better understand raw-output:
https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Invokingjq

Edited the answer implementing a more idiomatic solution using JQ's [`fromJson`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/v1.5/#Convertto/fromJSON)

```
get-secret-username: 
@ $(eval USERNAME = $(shell aws secretsmanager get-secret-value --secret-id vikings-aurora-postgres-secret | jq '.SecretString | fromjson | .username'))
@ echo "username: $(USERNAME)"
```